# jQuery preventDefault Not Behaving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple search function that is misbehaving. The search box is inside of a form that we do not want to submit when searching, so I have the setup below.

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.fn.onEnter = function(callback) {
        this.keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopPropagation();
                if (typeof callback == 'function')
                    callback.apply(this);
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
    $('#txtSearch').onEnter(function() {
        search();
        return false;
    });
    $('#search_btn').click(function() {
        search();
        return false;
    });

    function search() {
        alert('searching');
    }
});
```

The e.preventDefault() line isn't working, so the search function fires as well as the form submits. I've tried it with both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` with no luck.

Comment: Enter key inside the form will trigger the submit function of the form - so handle it in there

Comment: You are stopping the browser default keyup event not submit event.

Comment: i suggest you use `return false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stopping the browser default `keyup` event not `submit` event. Your best bet is to use `keydown` so that the enter key itself is stopped.

Also use `e.which` which is normalized for crossbrowser.

You can try adding a keydown handler to prevent enter key and do stuff inside keyup.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PSkvm/1/

```
jQuery.fn.onEnter = function(callback) {
    this.keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            //e.stopPropagation();
            if (typeof callback == 'function')
                callback.apply(this);
        }
    }).keydown(function (e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 13) {
           e.preventDefault();
         }
    });
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your code worked perfectly as is.

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault() doesn't work for forms. Try return false; instead.

Comment: I would expect them to work onsubmit and this is not binding the submit

Comment: try this: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ they have a beforeSend hook which, when returning false, blocks the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `e.keyCode` is not caught use

```
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
```

Modify your code to:

```
 var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(code == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (typeof callback == 'function')
       callback.apply(this);
  }
```